# Rails nested routing + shallow edit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use some routing like this:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :electricity_counters, :shallow => true do
    resources :electricity_bills, :shallow => true
  end
end
```

Creating a electricity_counter works fine, but edit doesn't work as expected..
If I visit electricity_counters/1/edit I only get blank fields and all my data is missing.

My _form.html.erb for that starts like this

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @customer.electricity_counters.build]) do |f| %>
```

and the controller methods for new and edit are like this:

```
# GET customers/1/electricity_counters/new
  def new
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    @electricity_counter = @customer.electricity_counters.build
  end

  # GET /electricity_counters/1/edit
  def edit
    @electricity_counter = ElectricityCounter.find(params[:id])
    @customer = @electricity_counter.customer
  end
```

In debug it seems to be that my @customer variable isn't set right.. but maybe I'm just to stupid to use that aptana debugger;)

The electricity_counter model has the association to a customer set by:

```
belongs_to :customer
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is this line.

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @customer.electricity_counters.build]) do |f| %>
```

It builds a new `electricity_counter` no matter what you want to do. Since you're handling that in the controller.

But since you want to use the same `_form` partial for both new and edit you have to be able to change the `form path`. Basically I ended up doing something like this:

Controller

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @electricity_counter = @customer.electricity_counters.build
  @path = [@customer, @electricity_counter]
end

def edit
  @electricity_counter = ElectricityCounter.find(params[:id])
  @customer = @electricity_counter.customer
  @path = @electricity_counter
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for(@path) do |f| %>
```

Also your `routes.rb` is off change it to this

```
resources :customers, :shallow => true do
  resources :electricity_counters, :shallow => true do
    resources :electricity_bills
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks :)
But there seems to be an other error.. if I open edit I get:
`NoMethodError in Electricity_counters#edit
undefined method `customer_electricity_counter_path' for #<#<Class:0x10cb659d8>:0x10cb61590>`

Comment: Your resource is `shallow` you don't need to preface `electricity_counter_path` with `customer`. But also I think you have your `routes.rb` backwards, I'll edit my answer real quick.

Comment: Hmm I fixed the routes.rb and changed my form_for method call to
`<%= form_for @electricity_counter do |f| %>`
That fixes the edit.. but after that the new route seems to be broken  :(
`No route matches {:format=>nil, :controller=>"electricity_counters"}`

Comment: You still need `form_for([@customer, @electricity_counter])`. Sorry I may be forgetting something important, I can't look at it again right now but I will in a couple hours.

Comment: Ok, I changed it back to and will wait for your answer :) 
<%= form_for([@customer, @electricity_counter]) do |f| %>

Comment: Sorry, I was missing something. You need the form to go both ways. I did it by changing the controller a little bit, I'll update my solution.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much :)
I've just started to learn rails and you helped me a lot!